# Multi-browser Selenium/web driver testing with Play Framework

Tags: java, selenium, playframework

I don't have any prior experience with Selenium/WebDriver tests. I know that Play supports Selenium out of the box, but frankly the built in support doesn't seem to match my expectations:

1. I want to setup an automated build that runs the tests on multiple browsers / OSes. I know sites like [SauceLabs](http://saucelabs.com/) give you easy access to many different browsers, and would like to leverage that, but from what I gathered the built-in Selenium tests won't play nice with that.
2. More generally, it seems that the built-in tests are written in HTML, and there's no support for writing tests in Java (which seems to me like a better option).

I tried extending UnitTest and using SauceLabs myself. This seemed to work well, but I hit a roadblock trying to run the same test on multiple browsers. I tried using [jUnit's Parametrized Tests](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html), but that didn't work out so well (I kept getting errors about my test classes having too many constructors).

Are there best practices for writing System/Selenium tests in Play that:

1. Are **easily** run on **multiple browsers** as part of a **continuous integration system**?
2. Are written in Java, not HTML?

Comment: regarding not being able to run multi-browser tests on the Java libraries from Sauce, you can grab this [JSON of all their browser/OS combos](http://saucelabs.com/rest/v1/info/browsers/webdriver) and reformat it with another utlity that 'builds' a hard-coded array of browsers into the jUnit test file. This overcame a similar issue I had with the PHP library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did develop this Play! module, which I think may also work for you:

https://github.com/miguelrgonzalez/Play--Selenium-webdrive

It's still in an really early phase but it's already functional.

Feel free to fork!

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely look at this when I get a chance. (accepted answer for the time being)

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly possible. However, it is difficult to achieve this effectively without using Selenium/WebDriver Grid. By default, many browsers will only allow one version of themselves to be installed on the system. Although you have control over which browser to launch, you have no control over which version (or you are limited to the currently installed version).

Using the Grid, you can leverage existing infrastructure with the following steps:

- Establish a Hub node
- Have different nodes (machines, virtual machines, etc.) connect to this Hub. These nodes each contain different browsers and these 'capabilities' are registered with the Hub upon connection.
- When a test is run, instead of running it against a local browser, dispatch the test to the Hub, which will attempt to find the best match for the capability you have specified within the nodes that have registered themselves on the Grid. The Grid will do all the necessary marshalling of messages back and forth such that you can run tests on the Grid transparently and with the same ease of use as if you were doing so locally.

For more information on the Grid, see [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2). Although this information is not related specifically to the Play Framework, hopefully it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything special in order to run Selenium 2/WebDriver tests with Play! Framework.

Simply write your RemoteWebDriver tests and extend them from play.test.UnitTest. Then, these tests will be executed by the Play! TestRunner and, obviously, the results will be saved in Play! standard way.